# 2D array in C++ with variable dimentions

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am teaching myself C++ and I have a doubt about arrays. I know that if I declare a 2D array like:

```
char board[8][8];
```

I create a 2D array with a height and a width of 8. But, I was wondering if there is a way to set those dimensions to variables so the user can input the height and width they want, I tried this in C++ and visual studio wasn't happy.

```
int rowSize = 0;  
int colSize = 0;
cin >> rowSize >> colSize;
char board[rowSize][colSize];
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: The size of arrays must be compile time constant. Use std::vector<> for dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: I would imagine your C++ book covers this topic? As it's fairly common. Worth a read!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged with `c++`, perhaps `std::vector` is for you. It's much like an array, but more convenient and well suited for this purpose. You can simply initialize a 2D Array of nested vectors with this initializer call (thanks to Bob__ for this much more simple solution):

```
int n = 5;
int m = 10;
std::vector<std::vector<char>> board (n, std::vector<char>(m, 'a'));
```

This creates the board and initializes all fields to `'a'`, per example. You can access and manipulate the data using the same syntax as with C style arrays:

```
char x = board[4][2];
board[3][3] = 'o';
```

Last but not least, there are lots of convenient features and functions that allow you to do things like copying it much more easily than with C-style arrays. Check out the documentation of `std::string` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: A vector of vectors is not the same as the multidimensional array in C. This requires more memory allocations and more indirect accesses, so it's far slower than the C solution.

Comment: That's right. The slowdown would probably be noticeable quickly on a massive board with millions of cells. I wouldn't do it like this on a board with millions of cells but I don't think that was OP's intention, so why not leverage a suitable container to solve the task in a nice and easy manner?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: did you really measure the overhead? It should seldom be observable on real world programs. But the data in not consecutively stored in a vector of vectors (much more like an array of pointers to arrays).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher For a beginner this is a good starting point (at least it introduces the Standard Library and avoids vendor specific non standard extensions), the next learning step being to write a proper class. I would have used the constructor, though: `std::vector<std::vector<char>> board (n, std::vector<char>(m, 'a'));`

Comment: I didn't mention any non standard extension. And yes, I measured the speed difference, and it is huge on "big" matrices. That's why all math libraries are implemented as a 1D array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Bob. That's much shorter, and a lot faster too! That's a 22x speedup on a 100x100 board. I don't use the std structure a whole lot, so I'm always glad to learn something. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate such matrices, use a vector and index it with `i + j * rowSize`.

The other construction is not c++ compliant, it's an gcc extension from C99 (Variable Length Arrays), and their equivalent (more or less) are a vector or a unique pointer to an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this you could do the follwing:

```
int* myPointer = nullptr;   // Pointer to int, initialize to nothing.
int sizeOfArray;           // Size needed for array
std::cin >> sizeOfArray;        // At runtime get the size of the array
myPointer = new int[sizeOfArray];  // Allocate array of specified size and save ptr in a.
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
    myPointer[i] = 0;    // Initialize all elements to zero.
}
delete[] myPointer;  // When done, free memory pointed to by myPointer.
myPointer = nullptr;     // Clear a to prevent using invalid memory reference.
```

Although I would strongly recommend you use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead.

Comment: With a vector or a unique pointer instead, then we are closer to the core guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot in conformant C++, because the standard does not define Variable Length Arrays (*).

If you do not need consecutive allocation (a true 2D array underlying storage), you can use a vector of vectors. This is generally the most simple and idiomatic way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>>(8, std::vector<char>(8, '\0'));
```

If you can accept a functionnal type access, you can build a custom container with an underlying 1D vector of size 64 (8*8), and an accessor method returning a reference.

If you want to mimic 2D container with an underlying true 2D array, then you are in trouble. I have tried to build a generic multi-dimensional container (code in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/196628/146901)), and realized that you cannot correctly implement random access iterators on non standard containers...

---

(*) of course, gcc gladly accept VLA in C++ as a documented extension to the language...